# What is wrong with this HQL query?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql

Trying HQL, total NHibernate n00b.

```
public IEnumerable<Log> GetLast(int numRecords, string severity)
{
    var query = _Session.CreateQuery(
        "from Log as l inner join fetch l.UserProfile order by l.TimeStamp desc where l.Severity in (:severities)")
        .SetParameterList("severities", Translator.SeverityOrHigher(severity))
        .SetMaxResults(numRecords)
        .Enumerable<Log>();

    return query;
}
```

`Translator.SeverityOrHigher` returns an `IList<string>`.

I have a `Log` object which references a `UserProfiles` object in many-to-one fashion.  The objects are persisted in the database as `Logs` and `UserProfiles`, respectively.

I am getting the following exception thrown on the `var query = ...` line:

```
Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTokenException' was thrown.
```

I have no idea what that even means, and a Google search wasn't especially helpful.  I don't know if there's a problem with the HQL, or the way I set this up.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a list and it is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used NHib for ages... have you tried to put the order by statement at the end? Probably it's working like this, by I always put at the end.

Comment: Right, that exception message wasn't very helpful :(